# Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret value for staging label

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

I've been trying to create secret on the command line as follows :

```
~/$ aws secretsmanager create-secret --name first-secret
{
    "ARN": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-2:123456789012:secret:first-secret-9ez7W2",
    "Name": "first-secret"
}
~/$ aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id first-secret

An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the GetSecretValue operation: Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret value for staging label: AWSCURRENT
```

If I create secret on AWS Console (accepting default choices), I can "get-secret-value" without problem.

What's the difference between AWS Console and command line in this regard ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The (unhelpful) error message is thrown because the secret value hasn't been set after creation.

Here's how you can get things working:

```
$ aws secretsmanager create-secret --name first-secret
$ aws secretsmanager put-secret-value --secret-id first-secret --secret-string "foo@"
$ aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id first-secret
```